# How to handle exceptions and cleanup on resources?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript:

```
let socket: WebSocket
try {
  socket = new WebSocket(path, options)
  // do some more stuff with socket
} catch (e) {
  socket.terminate()
  throw e
}
```

This a familiar pattern from Java.

But my IDE is complaining at `socket.terminate()`: `TS2454: Variable 'socket' is used before being assigned.`

The alternative just seems super clunky:

```
let socket: WebSocket | null = null
  try {
    socket = new WebSocket(path, options)
    // do some more stuff with socket
  } catch (e) {
    socket?.terminate()
    throw e
  }
```

Is there a better way?

I made a subtle change... maybe it's better:

```
let socket: WebSocket | undefined
  try {
    socket = new WebSocket(path, options)
    // do some more stuff with socket
  } catch (e) {
    socket?.terminate()
    throw e
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "clunky" way is the correct way, although if you don't use the socket again after the `try...catch` and you only re-throw after closing the (potentially-open) socket as an idempotent cleanup task, then the `catch` block is useless and can be replaced with `try...finally` to accomplish the same:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/PTAEEEBsBcAsHsCuBzWoCeSBOoCOiBTAZ2gEt4A7UAE3mIoHJpQBbAisy0U6AGlABGBAMYBDREQIYkoCVLhSARNAJYWpCqJWLWBOPGq8AUCACSoAA5ZiiNqDhbpiUKOuyiG5C9AB1AgIBleGEAaz1QSFIBLFd0UAB3HjQiRGE0USpwAAVTfkiw0EV4okUALiNSFgt4LGYAbz9A4LDoAF9QADMseBZQBmKGAG4jEzAATRlqUmpGZiIEePtYYikNJxx8Yk4KfiJ4UEAUAnt90QA3eGnZCmtILQJqe3QLKVVurCJDgALzahFbtwUvWW1nKv2E-ykwkoJEsWlgpVAAGFodAsKloDUsq5RGwVO8ADzQJ4EeAdXz+IKhPQAPgA2gAGAC6wzBENAUIoMPgFm2RARyM5qPRmOxuNUREJxNJ5KaVOgdIAjMyRpBwns5QjGpSWqAAD6gCiISCQUAAXgNRsgwyMqLidSMoFA6p15ooBEWWuaegAFBY4fxubyAJTWx0gUAAFQCBvgixCFFjHwczAABs69CnuB9fh0NDwCJA4hluIKMsIpNKU565ZnEnA1vWPgJIM1yo709BhiAAHoAfhGYbAtCdPSkLBqUhIiA6ZLryS90CMrSMuc0xrtDpHct7ADo8epNCpvSGl0YgA)

```ts
let socket: WebSocket | null = null;

try {
  socket = new WebSocket(path, options);

  // TS now knows that `socket` is definitely an instance of `WebSocket` within this block:
  socket;
//^? let socket: WebSocket

  // do some more stuff with socket
}
finally {
  socket?.terminate();
}
```

Comment: thank you - I'm new to typescript so not very confident yet

Comment: @MichaelWiles Great choice to start using it — there’s definitely a bit of learning curve, but the IntelliSense provides great DX while programming, and the compiler helps catch a bunch of potential bugs!

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE is right to complain - what if an exception occurs while the `WebSocket` is being created? In that case, `socket` wouldn't be set to anything. Your alternative seems to me not that clunky, and it handles the case that there's an error. If you use this pattern a lot, you could do this:

```js
type NullableWebSocket = WebSocket | null;
```